# Restrict access to nginx server location to a specific Docker container with "allow" directive

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, datadog

Edit: Tarun's answer does exactly what I asked for. Eugen's answer is also a very good solution. I ended up accepting Tarun's answer as correct, but using Eugen's. If you have a similar issue and are worried about other containers accessing the nginx status server, use Tarun's answer. If you'd rather stick to Docker's normal hostname scheme, use Eugen's.

+++ Original Question +++

I have an application that I build with docker-compose. I am trying to integrate monitoring through DataDog. I'm using DataDog's Agent container, and so far everything is working. I am trying to get nginx monitoring up and running by adapting [this tutorial](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-nginx-metrics/).

My application is defined in a docker-compose file like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    restart: always
    image: me/flask-app
    command: /home/app/flask/start_app.sh
    expose:
      - "8080"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    command: /runtime/start_nginx.sh
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    expose:
      - "81"
    volumes:
      - app-static:/app-static:ro
    links:
      - flask:flask

  datadog-agent:
    image: me/datadog-agent
    env_file: ./datadog-agent/dev.env
    links:
        - flask
        - nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /proc/mounts:/host/proc/mounts:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

Per the tutorial, I've added a server block to nginx that looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 81;

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

With this configuration, I can check the nginx status from within the nginx container. So far, so good. Now I would like to change the "allow" directive in the location block to allow access to the datadog-agent service only. However, I don't know the IP of the datadog-agent. When configuring access to the Flask uwsgi server, I was able to use directives like this:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass: flask:8080;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work for allow directives; if I try:

```
location /nginx_status {
    ...
    allow datadog-agent;
    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "datadog-agent" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx-status:8
```

How can I safely expose the nginx status to my monitoring container?

Comment: Too early to say not possible. I am working on a possible solution right now

Comment: Are you looking for [autodiscovery](https://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/autodiscovery/) ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Great--I will keep checking this post.

Comment: @stephenlechner--not exactly. Autodiscovery occurs on the DataDog side for discovering the nginx service; I'm trying to work out the nginx side--how to limit who can access the nginx server.

Comment: @nrlakin, done. Check my answer and see if it works for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we are running the service through `docker-compose` and our issue being we don't know the IP of the agent. So the simple solution is to know the IP before starting. And that means assigning our agent a specific IP

Here is a update `docker-compose` to do that

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    restart: always
    image: me/flask-app
    command: /home/app/flask/start_app.sh
    expose:
      - "8080"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    command: /runtime/start_nginx.sh
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    expose:
      - "81"
    volumes:
      - app-static:/app-static:ro
    links:
      - flask:flask
    networks:
      agent:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.101
      default:

  datadog-agent:
    image: me/datadog-agent
    env_file: ./datadog-agent/dev.env
    links:
        - flask
        - nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /proc/mounts:/host/proc/mounts:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    networks:
      agent:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.100
networks:
  agent:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```

Now you can do two possible things

```
server {
  listen 172.25.0.101:81;

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 172.25.0.100;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

You can listen only on `172.25.0.101` which is accessible only container running on agent network. Also you can add `allow 172.25.0.100` to only allow the agent container to be able to access this.

Answer (score 10):

Think differently :)

Do bind a nginx-server (vhost) on port 10080 **in addition** - that server does offer the status location and what you need.

Server on 80/443 is also there and ONLY that one is bound/exposed to host ( exposed to the outer world ).

Since datadog is part of your docker-network / service network, it can still access 10080 in the internal network, but nobody else from the outer network.

Bulletproof, easy - no strings attached.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. I remove the allow/deny directives from my server block. I listen on some high random port (I'm currently using 81, but it could be 10080). I expose the port (just as I am now, and not using "ports" directive). The (pseudo) port is accessible to all linked containers, but not to a physical port on the host. DataDog can access the stats, and so could my Flask container, but nothing outside can. I offload responsibility for protecting the data from nginx to docker, but I'm fine so long as no one gets into another linked container (then I'm screwed anyway). Correct?

Comment: exactly. Be sure you mean `expose` from the dockerfile, not as some say expose on the "host" ( thats not what you ment i think). We can say, 10080 is a private port to the containers. And you can choose any port you like, but highports make sense here, its a custom thing - you do not want to get into the way of others.
If someone gets into your docker-server on the host, he is root and there is nothing you can protect against, right. But that is as safe as docker is, and most other linux things.

Comment: I ended up accepting Tarun's answer, since it does exactly what I asked for, but I think I'll probably go this route as it seems less brittle to use Docker's DNS. I'm going to edit the question to credit your answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

There are two (easier) ways to go about it.

First one is `docker-compose` but since I already have a setup running since 2 years which doesn't use docker-compose, I went for the 2nd way.

Second way is `Allow` Directive with a range of IPs.

Eg:

```
    location /stub_status {
        stub_status;

        allow 172.18.0.0/16;   # This is my local docker IP range
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;  $ This is my production server IP range
        deny all;              # deny all other hosts   
 }
```

I am not security expert, but mostly `192.168.*` IP range is for local networks, not sure about `172.18.*` range though.

To get more idea about this IP range thing and CIDR stuff, refer below links
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html

https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing

Comment: AFAICT Docker uses 172.16.0.0/12 (which includes 172.18.*), which is [reserved as a "Private Address Space"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918), so this seems safe and great to me, thanks!